# Statusbar Item Color change as that of instagram

Tags: android, colors, instagram, statusbar

How to change item colors of status bar as that of instagrams.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have already got a way do this, it's for minsdkversion > 23 which can be done in build gradle and we just have to add:

```
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

in our style.xml

Answer (score 0):

You change change it by modifying this theme property

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but it looks like transparent status bar
u can use following code for make it transparent..
put this code in Activity onCreate() method

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }
    }
```